# Make an checkbox return an int [Java]

Tags: java, events, return

I'm currently stuck on this problem. I would like if a checkbox is checked, it should return a value, Yet when you change the public to int you get an error. It seems to work only with void and void doesn't return anything. Is there a way to do this?

```
public class event3 implements ItemListener {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent checkboxdetails) {
            if(moredetailscheck.isSelected()) {
                return moredetailsbox = 1;
            } else {
                return moredetailsbox = 0;
            }

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event handlers are not designed to return something.
These methods are invoked as the related event occurs.
So what you have to do is capturing the information that interests you during the handler invocation.
You can for example store the information in an instance field :

```
private int moredetailsbox;
...
if(moredetailscheck.isSelected()) {
    moredetailsbox = 1;
} else {
    moredetailsbox = 0;
}
```

Comment: Deleting my answer in favor of this one.

Comment: It's an unnecessary duplicate.